# Swapping floppies in FreeDOS+Qemu

Tags: qemu, freedos

I am trying to replace a floppy inside a qemu machin running freedos 1.1. I remove the old floppy and inserts the new using change floppy0. Now when I dir A: nothing has changed. If I try to run a program that was on the old floppy, it cannot start it. After that, I dir A: again and now it is the new disk content. These floppies are vfd files.

It seems like a bug somewhere or should I flush the state of Qemu somehow (i have tried commit all but that does not help)